# "Class not registered" when running a (working) SeleniumBasic VBA macro from a VBScript and Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, vba, class

I have a VBA macro using SeleniumBasic that runs >perfectly< from a command button in Excel 2019. I need this macro running from the Windows 10's Task Scheduler and when calling the same macro from a VBScript within Task Scheduler it produces a run time error "Class not registered" at this line:

```
Set MyDriver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
```

This is the script I'm using with the Task Scheduler:

```
Dim ObjExcelApp
Dim ObjWorkbook
Set ObjExcelApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set ObjWorkbook = ObjExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SeleniumBasic_Test\WorkbooWithMacro.xlsm")
ObjExcelApp.Run "TestSeleniumBasic"
ObjWorkbook.Close False
ObjExcelApp.Quit
Set ObjExcelApp = Nothing
```

Nothing fancy here, just calling the Public Sub TestSeleniumBasic().

I tested the macro with .EdgeDriver and got the same "Class not registered" error. Again, the macro runs without issues from Excel.

Comment: Make sure that you added the reference `Selenium Type library`.

Comment: It is added. The macro runs without issues from Excel.